# Need to write a program that takes in at least 4 digits (3453) and prints out: "Three thousands four hundreds 5 tens and 3 ones"

Tags: c++

I think I'm on the right track and have all the elements i need, but i'm not too sure how to use classes / token and might have some other things formatted wrong.

```
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>


 using namespace std;

 class token {
 public:
            int value;
            string unit;

            }


 int main() {

 token t;
 vector<token> v;
 string unit = ""

 cin>>x;
 while (x!=0) {
    t.value=x%10;
    if (unit==" "}
        t.unit = "ones";
    else if (unit == "ones")
        t.unit = "tens"
    else if (unit = "tens")
        t.unit = "hundreds"
    else if (unit = "hundreds")
        t.unit = "thousands"

    v.pushback(t);
    x=x/10;
 }
  v_t.push_back("zero")
  v_t.push_back("one")
  v_t.push_back("two")
  v_t.push_back("three")
  v_t.push_back("four")
  v_t.push_back("five")
  v_t.push_back("six")
  v_t.push_back("seven")
  v_t.push_back("eight")
  v_t.push_back("nine")

  cout<< "This is ";
  for(int i = v.size()-1; i>=0, i--) {
        cout<<v_t[v[i].value]<<" "<< v[i].unit << " "}


 }
```

Everything I got here was taken from my notes, but was arranged in a different order. When I try to run it, I get and error message: "New types may not be defined in new types"

Comment: Why not **five thousand three hundred  fifty three**?

Answer (score 2):

There are many compile errors, to take care of the first one, put the semicolon at the end of the class:

```
class token {
 public:
            int value;
            string unit;

            };
```

For the second one, add a semicolon at the end of the declaration of unit:

```
string unit = "";
```

Third one, define "x":

```
int x;
```

Fourth, change '}' for ')' here:

```
if (unit==" ")
```

There are many more, sorry.
Add semicolons at the ends of all statements to start.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mistyping here or you forget all semicolons? and beside that you write `unit = "tens"` for comparing `unit` and `"tens"`? shouldn't it be `unit == "tens"`? and to check for empty string replace `if( unit = " " )` with `if( unit.empty() )`

Answer (score 0):

In this assignment, I wouldn't use a `std::vector`, but a fixed length array.

In C language terms *(to show the thought)*:

```
struct Text_Entry
{
    unsigned int value; // Don't deal with negatives with words.
    const char * const text;
};

// Here's the table
struct Text_Entry  conversion_table[] = 
{
    {0, "zero"},
    {1, "one"},
    {2, "two"},
//...
    {10, "ten"},
    {11, "eleven"},
//...
    {20, "twenty"},
    {30, "thirty"},
    {40, "forty"},
};
```

The compiler will load the table for you before your program starts, eliminating the need to use `push_back` for every case.  The `value` field allows you to arrange the entries in any order.

If you are allowed to, prefer `std::map`.

Don't use the table for every combination.  For example 21 would use the entry for 20 and the entry for 1.  Similarly for 135.

HTH.